# Git tag pointing to commit that doesn't appear in the logs

Tags: git

I ran a script which was supposed to create a git tag.

When I search for that tag: `git show-ref --tags`

I get a commit: `020795b07753c02034500f10f17dbc82edf refs/tags/my-tag`

Then, when I search for the branch containing that commit:

```
git branch --contains 020795b07753c02034500f10f17dbc82edf
```

I get a branch: `feature/my-feature`

The problem is that if I search `020795b07753c02034500f10f17dbc82edf` through the logs of `feature/my-feature` (obtained with `git log`), I can't find it.

Any idea why the tag is pointing to a commit that isn't in the logs?

Comment: What happens if you do `git cat-file -p 020795b07753c02034500f10f17dbc82edf` ?

Comment: ```object 020795b07753c02034500f10f17dbc82edf
type commit
tag my-tag

[maven-release-plugin] copy for tag my-tag```. The last line appears because I'm using `maven-release-plugin` to generate the tag.

Comment: Sounds very weird that `git branch --contains` says it is in the branch, but `git log` says it is not. How did you search the git log output?

Did you try doing `git log feature/my-feature | grep 020795b` ?

Comment: @Alderath Yes, and the output is empty.

Comment: Hang on, is that hash a reference to the tag object or the commit object?

Comment: Because if you do `git cat-file -p HASH` and get back an object that *refers* to that hash, something has gone haywire on disk in your .git/objects directory.

Comment: Actually, I didn't know you can have a hash reference to a tag. I thought you can only have a hash reference to a commit.

Comment: You can if you make a tag *object*, if you simply do `git tag xyz` you get just a tag reference, but if you do `git tag -a xyz -m 'message'` you get a tag *object* as well as a tag reference. The reference will then refer to the tag object instead of the commit object. I think one of the main reasons is that you can then sign the tag and such.

Comment: But the hash that identifies a git object cannot refer to an object that *contains* that hash, I doubt it is feasible mathematically to even create such an object with the checksum system. So the fact that when you do `git cat-file -p HASH`, you get back an object that contains the very same hash, you seem to have some problems with the git objects.

Comment: The hash reference is to the commit object.

Comment: Then why does your comment above contain information like `tag my-tag` and such? It should contain information like the hash of the tree object, the author and committer, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As Lasse V. Karlsen said in the comments, what you have is an *annotated tag*.

The part that does not make sense is your comment-answer to what happens if you run `git cat-file -p 020795b07753c02034500f10f17dbc82edf`.  You said you got:

```
object 020795b07753c02034500f10f17dbc82edf
type commit
tag my-tag [maven-release-plugin]
copy for tag my-tag
```

This would imply that you have found another hash collision: a tag object whose ID is `020795b07753c02034500f10f17dbc82edf`, yet which one which points to a commit object whose ID is also `020795b07753c02034500f10f17dbc82edf`.  This is literally impossible—not that a *collision* is impossible (see https://shattered.it/), but rather that Git has stored two different objects under a single ID.  This is because Git's "true name" for an object, the way it finds the object's contents, *is* the hash ID.  Once Git has stored one object with one ID, it refuses to store another, different object with the same ID.  If `020795b07753c02034500f10f17dbc82edf` is already a commit, an attempt to drop a tag in under the name `020795b07753c02034500f10f17dbc82edf` is simply rejected.

---

Here is an example of an annotated tag in the Git repository for Git itself:

```
$ git show-ref --tags
[massive amount of output snipped]
f883596e997fe5bcbc5e89bee01b869721326109 refs/tags/v2.9.3
```

Here `v2.9.3` is a tag name—a reference in the `refs/tags/` [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace)—pointing to Git object `f883596e997fe5bcbc5e89bee01b869721326109`.  The object itself is an *annotated tag:*

```
$ git cat-file -t f883596e997fe5bcbc5e89bee01b869721326109
tag
```

and its contents are the tag object, which points to the commit object:

```
$ git cat-file -p f883596e997fe5bcbc5e89bee01b869721326109
object e0c1ceafc5bece92d35773a75fff59497e1d9bd5
type commit
tag v2.9.3
tagger Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1471018679 -0700

Git 2.9.3
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1
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=PhTI
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

(this particular tag has a [GPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard) signature).  The actual *commit* is `e0c1ceafc5bece92d35773a75fff59497e1d9bd5`.  It is this (different) commit object that is contained in various branches.  The tag object is in *no* branches.  Aside from its hash ID, the way you—or Git—find the tag object is by looking up the tag name, `refs/tags/v2.9.3`.  One then finds the *commit* by reading the tag object.

Since this tag object refers to additional Git object `e0c1ceafc5bece92d35773a75fff59497e1d9bd5`, that is the *target* (my term) of this annotated tag.  The tag object claims that the target has type `commit`, so `git cat-file -t` should say it is a commit, and it does:

```
$ git cat-file -t e0c1ceafc5bece92d35773a75fff59497e1d9bd5
commit
```

and the commit object in turn looks normal:

```
$ git cat-file -p e0c1ceafc5bece92d35773a75fff59497e1d9bd5
tree 3cc4bf42e1b9aaa3c650af7247019890f7e01c95
parent 9b601eafd1437df2e11b032bfbfd1ac5d32d3290
author Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1471018671 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com> 1471018671 -0700

Git 2.9.3

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
```

and all is well in Git-land.